# count($array) not working in if statement

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to apply a `fade` class to all strings of 100 words or more.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
$descArray = explode(" ", stripslashes($longDesc));
echo "word count for array: ".count($descArray);
$shortDesc = implode(" ", array_splice($descArray, 0, 100));
if(count($descArray) >= 100) {
    print "<div class='fade'>".$shortDesc."</div>";
} else {
    print "<div>".$shortDesc."</div>";
}
```

According to the source code upon review, the `fade` class is only getting applied to (what it seems to be) lengths of 200 or more - even though it's specified to apply the class to all strings with a length of 100 or more. I tested with a lorem generator - a string split into an array of 199 never got the fade class applied to it, but when split into an array of 200 it did.

I'm sure I've made a silly mistake here, but what is it?

Comment: `if(count($descArray) >= 100) {` -> `if(strlen($descArray) >= 100) {`

Comment: @Rizier123 I think he wants word count instead of string length

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you use `str_word_count()` php function which does the thing you tried to implement?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php

Try this:

```
$descArray = explode(" ", stripslashes($longDesc));
$shortDesc = stripslashes($longDesc);
$wordCount = str_word_count($shortDesc);

if($wordCount < 100) {
   echo "<div>".$shortDesc."</div>";
} else {
   $shortDesc = implode(" ", array_splice($descArray, 0, 100))
   echo '<div class="fade">'.$shortDesc.'</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're splicing your array before getting count. [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) splice it assign it to itself.

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
array_splice($array, 0,3);
print_r($array);
```

New array will be `array(1, 2, 3, 4);`

And for counting text size [strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) and [str_word_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) for counting words is a better choise.

Answer (score 0):

It's a **strlen** function to count string length.